# A software to convert .pdf files into multiple svg files (one per pdf page)?

Tags: pdf, svg

I have a website on which I'm publishing texts that I'm often modifying. It is demanding too much time to format them in html/css each time, so I wanted a way to just save them in a specific format, put them on the server, and by the magic of some kind of program/script, the text would appear formatted in the desired canvas on my webpage. Last thing, which complicate everything, texts can contain a lot of pages (5 to 50 pages) and I need them to be tied to "previous" and "next" button, which means that the pages have to be separated (or so I don't think it is possible otherwise to keep that kind of control buttons)

I've seen that using .svg allows to have more control over the style. Yet there are programs that convert my texts, that I can save into .pdf, to .svg. But the problem is that it usually do one page at a time only (like inkscape).

Online solution can split a .pdf into multiple .svg pages, but the render is random, most of the time unusable.

So, I'm open for any solution that could cross your minds.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations SE Braisque!  We will need a little more information to help you.  On which operating system(s) should this software run?  Are you looking for gratis solutions or commercial recommendations?

Comment: check out  PDF2SVG http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/ and this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120567/convert-pdf-to-svg and this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048205/how-to-programmatically-convert-svg-to-pdf-on-windows

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me :) Sorry for having been unclear. Configuring pdf2svg is far beyond my knowledge unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You indicated that splitting the PDF pages into separate SVG files could help you, provided the resulting SVG has proper formatting.

If you haven't tried it already, the [LEADTOOLS ePrint](https://www.eprintdriver.com/) printer driver and converter can convert to separate SVG pages. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of this driver). To use it, print the source document to the ePrint printer, then save the printout as Vector SVG.

I recommend that you try the time-limited [free evaluation edition from here](https://www.eprintdriver.com/Download).

If the resulting SVG is suitable for your needs, consider buying ePrint. If it's not, simply uninstall it.